# Django - URL with www is not safe

Tags: url, web

I have a website at `bukimlan.com`. We set the default site as shown `https://bukimlan.com`. There is no problem with this `URL`. We have `SSL` and secure.

But if the user comes with `https://www.bukimlan.com` `URL`, there is a not safe error in the address line. And in mobile, `Google` says your connection is not private with `www` `URL`.

`Google` indexed some pages with `www`, so we need to solve this problem.

Comment: what does that have to do with django and python? please consider removing those tags or adding some explanation... what is the CN (common name) in your certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SSL certificate is only valid for bukimlan.com. You should generate a new certificate that includes both domains (or a wildcard certificate).

It looks like you're already using LetsEncrypt. If you're using the [`certbot`](https://certbot.eff.org/) client, you can generate a new certificate with both domains by specifying `-d bukimlan.com -d www.bukimlan.com` on the command line. If you'd like a wildcard certificate instead, follow the instructions on the certbot homepage to find the specific steps you need to take.

Edit: If both of those domains are serving the same content, you probably also want to make one your canonical domain and redirect the other to it.

Comment: Actually, redirect should be better cause of same content. What should i do? We tested different browsers and computers. Some of them is ok, www redirect to non-www. But others is not work. We can not recognize the difference between computers, they are using same network.

Comment: @haşimuyanık That seems like a separate issue that should be a new Stack Overflow question if you need help debugging it. If the certificate issue is solved, please mark it as accepted, and open a new question for the redirect / client problem.